# laravel on cpanel display error 500

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, server-error

i uploaded my project to godaddy cpanel file manger. everything worked well at first but later, i wanted to do and update and i trashed the files out and uploaded the new files but it started slowing This page isn’t working
**campustalkative.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500** i replaced my laravel index.php file contents with just a hello world php script and everything worked well but my laravel file gives droping that same error which makes me suspect that my laravel project aint configured well or i might have trashed some files please help!.i still have my .htaccess and web.config files.

```
<configuration>   <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

web.config file

Comment: Check your server error logs, and the logs found in `storage/logs`. there's a hint there somewhere.

Comment: my server error log is empty and nothing in storage/logs. please any more suggestions? maybe i have trashed a necessary file? or some configurations?